# css3 "::after" pseudo-element not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

I want to add a triangle after a div tag.Therefore i used css3 after pseudo-element. But it's not working. Following is my css rule.

```
.header-wrapper .part1 ::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: solid 48.35px #f21e1e;
    border-bottom: solid 48.35px transparent;
    border-top: solid 48.35px transparent;
}
```

Following is my html part

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="part1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

In order for the pseudo element to be generated, you need to [specify a `content` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html). The value is otherwise assumed to be the default, `none` - which is likely why it isn't working in your case. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/dkejh9k8/)

```
.header-wrapper .part1::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: solid 48.35px #f21e1e;
    border-bottom: solid 48.35px transparent;
    border-top: solid 48.35px transparent;
}
```

Based on the CSS you posted, you should also remove the space between `.part1 ::after`.

Comment: It should also be noted that the space between `.part1` and `::after` in the question needs to be removed as this would be a child selector.